# How to ignore selected disabled option in select multiselect dropdown

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-validate

```
<select name="purchasableId" id="multiSelect" class="metre" multiple='multiple' required> <option disabled selected value='abc'>abc</option> <option value='xyz'>xyz</option></select>
```

---

This given example showing me an required alert with validation js as selected option is in disable status .
I want if any option is selected in select drop-down shouldn't show required validation as it is selected, should not matter where it is disabled or not.

```
$("#multiSelect").validate({     
                ignore:"option:selected,disabled"
            });
```

Comment: I could not understand what you really  want? If you disable an option it is not available to select and if it is not available to select it is not being validated

Comment: You can't select a disabled option so it doesn't make sense to validate it.

Comment: I don't want to show an required alert if any option of select is selected whether it is disabled or not

Comment: The `ignore` option is for ignoring (not validating) certain `form` data input elements when validating.  Example, ignore an `input`, ignore a `select`, ignore a `textarea`, etc.  You are trying to ignore `option` elements.  `option` elements are not `form` data input elements, they are children of a `select` element, which are not used by themselves.  You can ignore the `select`, but you cannot ignore a specific part inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try do it this way:

```
//Use form id
$("#form").validate({
   ignore: ".no-validate"
})
```

Then add the class to your select:

```
<select name="purchasableId" id="multiSelect" class="metre no-validate" multiple='multiple' required> <option disabled selected value='abc'>abc</option>
<option value='xyz'>xyz</option>
</select>
```

See fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/designtocode/3ok1ratu/6/

Comment: You're ignoring (not validating) the whole `select` element.  That's not what he's asking at all.  He wants to ignore specific individual `option` elements that are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Got solution by adding rule

```
$( "#selector_id" ).rules( "add", {
              required: function() {
                    var opion_selected_required =true;  //if selected option not found fire validation required
                    $('#selector_id option').each(function() {
                        if($(this).is(':selected'))
                        {
                            opion_selected_required = false; //if selected option found do not fire validation required (where option disabled or enabled no matter)
                        }
                    });
                    return opion_selected_required;                              
                }
            });
```

Comment: FYI - you don't need to do this via the `.rules()` method.  You can just as easily put your custom function for the `required` rule along with all the other rules in your `.validate()` method.